# How to implement method which gonna swipe on the iPhone left and right while will find correct app/element on the homescree?

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, ui-automation

I am using c#, Appium, VisualStudio, iPhone

These methods below works fine and does swipe. But How to implement method which gonna swipe on the iPhone left and right while will find correct app/element on the home page/screen ??

```
public void SwipeHomeScreenLeftToRight()
    {
        int[] screenSize = pageElement.Page.GetWindowSize();
        int height = screenSize[0];
        int width = screenSize[1];

        _Swipe(30, height / 2, width - 1, height / 2, 1);


    }


    public void SwipeHomeScreenRigthToLeft()
    {
        int[] screenSize = pageElement.Page.GetWindowSize();
        int height = screenSize[0];
        int width = screenSize[1];

        Swipe(width - 1, height / 2, 1, height / 2, 1);

    }
```

Comment: You mean, on the actual home screen, outside of your app?

Comment: yes , on the actual iPhone screen

Comment: Then I don't think this is possible due to app sandobxing, and the fact the background operation is quite limited on iOS. Unless of course you are working on a jailbroken device. Why do you need this?

Comment: It is possible ,methods above works. This is for automation test :) SeleniumWebDriver+Appium

Comment: Shouldn't automation tests start by launching your app, and then your test code goes from there?